# Javascript: How to call base class function before overriding in derived class?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I am trying to use inheritance in JavaScript. I want to know how to call the base class method in the derived class.

My Base Class:

```
class BaseClass {

    constructor (args, kwargs) {

        this.query_params = args
        /* other initial variables in base class */
    }

    retrive () {

        let offset  =   parseInt(getData(this.query_params, 'offset', 0))
        let limit   =   parseInt(getData(this.query_params, 'limit', 20))

        /* extra functionalities */

    }
}

module.exports = BaseClass
```

My derived class:

```
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {

    constructor (args, kwargs) {
        super(args, kwargs)

        this.model  =   dataBase.ArticleList // using sequelize for database
    }


    retrive () {

        /* functionalities here */
    }


}

module.exports = DerivedClass
```

I want to call the BaseClass retrive funtion in the DerivedClass before I run any other code in the DerivedClass.

I tried seraching for the solution but couldn't find any. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `super` keyword much like `this`, but it will refer to the base class object instead:

```
super.retrive();
```

See also the [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Using_super_in_classes).

Answer (score 4):

Just call `this.retrive();` right after your `super` call:

```js
class BaseClass {
  constructor (args, kwargs) {
    this.query_params = args
    /* other initial variables in base class */
  }
  retrive () {
    console.log('retrive');
  }
}
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor (args, kwargs) {
        super(args, kwargs)
        this.retrive();
        
        console.log('other stuff');
    }
    retrive_list () {
        /* functionalities here */
    }
}
const instant = new DerivedClass();
```

Comment: Hi, it works if the function name in BaseClass is different than DerivedClass. Any Idea how to do it for same function names?